# Dynamic queries for SQLite Database using Tkiner Python

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter, dynamic

I have a SQLite database, and I am using Tkinter Python,so what i want to do is that an user enter the first or tow letter, and in the same time my program gave some suggestions based on a list in my database.

My question is, how can i make the dynamic query?

thanks

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow... https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Pick one of [`[python][tkinter] autocomplete`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+%5Bpython%5D%5Btkinter%5D+autocomplete)

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution I used (event)

```
def dynamicsearch(event):
    value=Username.get().strip()
    for row in mydatbse.searchData(value,Password.get()):
        Userssbx.insert(END,row,str(""))
```